# PHP: How can i combine 2 different array into one

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to combine 2 array into one array?

My first array shows the amount calculated money per day.

```
$ArrayBefore[] = $amountOfTransactions_prDayArrayBefore;
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [09/02] => 102.83
        [08/02] => 3852.49
        [07/02] => 2619.23
        [06/02] => 1135.24
        [05/02] => 2391.4
        [04/02] => 2376.15
        [03/02] => 2760.05
        [02/02] => 1946.41
    )
)
```

My second array shows the amount transactions per day.

```
$ArrayTrans[] = $amountOfTransactions_prDayArrayTrans;
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [09/02] => 2
        [08/02] => 30
        [07/02] => 30
        [06/02] => 15
        [05/02] => 36
        [04/02] => 31
        [03/02] => 28
        [02/02] => 14
    )
)
```

Is there a way to combine both of them to one array. I want them to look like this, so i can spit them out in a table.

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [09/02] => 102.83 => 2
        [08/02] => 3852.49 => 30
        [07/02] => 2619.23 => 30
        [06/02] => 1135.24 => 15
        [05/02] => 2391.4 => 36
        [04/02] => 2376.15 => 31
        [03/02] => 2760.05 => 28
        [02/02] => 1946.41 => 14
    )
)
```

Comment: `[09/02] => 102.83 => 2` - this does not make sense, what do you mean with it? Should it be like `[09/02] => Array ( 102.83,  2 )` ? Could you provide an example how you want to access the values in the combined array?

Answer (score 0):

i call first array $a , second array $b

```
foreach ( $a[0] as $key=>$value )
{
    $c[0]["$value"] = $b[0][$key];
}
```

and

```
   $c = array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=8)
          '102.83' => int 2
          '3852.49' => int 30
          '2619.23' => int 30
          '1135.24' => int 15
          '2391.4' => int 36
          '2376.15' => int 31
          '2760.05' => int 28
          '1946.41' => int 14
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [array_merge()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$result = array_merge($ArrayBefore, $ArrayTrans);
```

EDIT:

Understand that my php is rusty, but how about something along the lines of:

```
foreach($ArrayBefore[] as $key => $value) {
    $tmpPair[$value] = $ArrayTrans[0][$key];
    $newArray[$key] = $tmpPair;
}
```

You may also be able to simplify it

```
foreach($ArrayBefore[] as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[$key][$value] = $ArrayTrans[0][$key];
}
```

Comment: But the output is going to be like this then: Array ( [0] => Array ( [09/02] => 160.83 [08/02] => 3852.49 [07/02] => 2619.23 [06/02] => 1135.24 [05/02] => 2391.4 [04/02] => 2376.15 [03/02] => 2760.05 [02/02] => 1946.41 ) [1] => Array ( [09/02] => 3 [08/02] => 30 [07/02] => 30 [06/02] => 15 [05/02] => 36 [04/02] => 31 [03/02] => 28 [02/02] => 14 ) )

Comment: It's not going to work like the OP wants, but it's how they can be combined.

Comment: Okay. Is there a way to do it in a another way? Preferably in such a way that the desired output

Comment: oops. Should have paid more attention. I think you'll just to loop through the first array and create a third array manually in the format you are looking for.

Comment: No i deleted that a while ago :/ Can you provide a example of your idea?